# Can a certificate with same CN be used in two remote qmgrs?

Tags: ibm-mq

Can you use the same certificate for two MQ Qmgrs running in different servers? I know if you have the qmgrs in the same server you can use the same cert, but when you have two servers the CN(common name)of the certificate is the hostname, so it would be different for both and i am not sure if both of them can share the same cert.

Comment: IBM MQ  or something else.  If IBM MQ, what version?

Comment: @JoshMc it is MQ 9.1.4 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IBM MQ product only checks the DN value of the peer queue manager cert against the `SSLPEER` configured on the channel.  MQ unlike browsers (and other software such as LDAP libraries) does zero validation of the DN (or SAN) against the hostname of the remote host.

There is no technical reason the same cert could not be used on two servers, this is very common when you have HA and DR configurations.

I would consider it best practice to have unique certs for each queue manager since these are used to prove identity.

Security implications for using the same certificate on two separate queue managers:

1. You have to copy the private key somehow between the two machines.
2. There are now two places an attacker could gain the single Certificate.
3. You can't rely on the SSLPEER feature on the client to ensure you connect to one specific QM but you could still ensure you have connected to a QM hosting that cert.
4. You can't rely on the SSLPEER feature on the connecting queue manager (SDR channel for example) to ensure you connect to one specific QM but you could still ensure you have connected to a QM hosting that cert.

Comment: As JoshMc says here there are no technical reasons you couldn't use the same certificate in 2 seperate queue managers but there are security implications for doing so.

1. You have to copy the private key somehow off a machine.
2. There are now two places an attacker could gain the single Certificate.
3. You can't rely on the SSLPEER feature on the client to ensure you got to one specific QM but you could still ensure you have got to a QM hosting that cert.
4. Same as above but with your QM acting as a client.
There are most likely other concerns but this is a quick list of some of them.

Comment: @RobParker great detailed list on reasons why it is bad. With your permission I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score -2):

No, client should reject connection as untrusted.
Client connects to particular server and CN in certificate, which server sends back to client, must be the same as is server name.
You can use SAN (Subject alternative name) to put there more FQDN or wildcard (*) in CN.

If client connects to MQserver1:1414, servers certficate must have MQserver1 in CN or in SAN of certificate

Comment: For the IBM MQ product this is 100% false, it does **NOT** validate the CN or SAN automatically against the hostname. There is not even a way to configure it to do this automatically.   The only checking that can be configured is via the `SSLPEER` configured on channels and/or `CHLAUTH` rules.